# Messaging system design

Tags: interop, soa, messaging, amqp

I am looking for a way to send requests and receive call backs from another party.

The only gotcha is that we do not now how it will be designed/deployed on the receiver side.

We do have the text/JSON based messages defined and agreed upon.

Looked at RabbitMQ and others, but each requires a server that would need to be maintained.

Thanks,

Comment: Could you please share some more information? Some things that would help:

- Detail the problem your trying to address with messaging.
- Detail about the message format may also help people.
- Size information about your message format, lots of bytes or few?
- What response time is acceptable to your application? milliseconds, minuets, hours?
- Expected requests per second?

I'd suggest checking out video's of presentations by Joe Armstrong or any of the Erlang guys about messaging, the concepts still apply in any language.

http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Message-Passing-Concurrency

Comment: Darn, didn't realise the comment would be formatted like that :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RabbitMQ is pretty easy to maintain. You would use two queues, one for requests and the other for replies. Use the AMQP correlation_id header to tag requests and replies so that when a reply message is received it can be matched with the orginal request.

However, if a broker is not for you, then use ZeroMQ. It is a client library available for a dozen or more languages and it enforces messaging patterns over top of sockets. This means that your app does not have to do all the low level socket management. Instead you declare the socket as REQ/REP and ZeroMQ handles all the rest. You just send messages in any format you desire, and you get messages back.

I've used ZeroMQ to implement a memcache style application in Python using REQ/REP.

Answer (score 1):

@user821692: You have to agree not only message format but also destination/transport protocol. For e.g. if both communicating parties has access to same queue physically located anywhere, then they can communicate pre-defined messages. You may also look of sending messages over HTTP..